# ssh and run a ps on remote server failing

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I have a shell script that is trying to ssh to a remote server and get the process id of a process on the remote server. When i run the command seperately it works but from the shell script it is just spitting a blank line.
This is my input

```
ps -ef|grep MYJVM
user1 10796 10531 0 11:39 ? 00:00:00 /bin/bash /opt/bin/startDataEngine Host2 77633b8f-3401-0000-0080-918586aba15f MYJVM
user1 10798 10796 0 11:39 ? 00:00:18 DataEngine Host2 77633b8f-3401-0000-0080-918586aba15f MYJVM`
```

Now when run the following command from the remote host `Host1` it works.

```
/usr/bin/ssh -t -q root@host2.serv.com "ps -ef|grep -w MYJVM|grep -w '[D]ataEngine Host2\'|awk '{print \$10}'"`
```

gives me

```
`7633b8f-3401-0000-0080-918586aba15f`
```

But when I run the same command from shell script I get a blank.

```
#!/bin/ksh
jvm=MYJVM
host=Host2
spid=$(ssh -t -q root@host2.serv.com "ps -ef|grep -w $jvm|grep -w '[D]ataEngine $host'|awk '{print $10}'")

echo $spid
```

I tried using double quotes for the variables `$jvm` and for the second grep `[D]ataEngine $host` but no use.

Comment: It could be that the 'print $10' is being interpreted by bash prior to the ssh call. Have you tried removing the $10 to see if you are getting any output from the command?  `'{ print }'`

Comment: @invalidentry Yes you are right. Didn't think that was the cause. How do i bypass that to get the required output?

Comment: Escape the dollar sign. `\$`

Comment: Done. Thanks everyone.